# How to pass an option into custom vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I made a custom Vue component and published it through npm. My component is working as I expected in my main project but with current usage, users would need to send too much props to use my component efficiently and without duplicate code.

I installed my component as

```js
//index.js in component folder
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.vue";

export default {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.component("my-component", MyComponent);
  }
};
```

and registered at my project as

```js
//main.js in project folder
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyComponent from 'my-component'

Vue.use(MyComponent)
```

using my custom component in my `.vue` files as:

```html
<my-component v-model="myData" prop1="prop1" prop2="prop2" prop3="prop3"></my-component>
```

Since that prop usage looks so untidy and causes too many code duplicate for myself, I want to register that props in options and pass through my component. But couldn't figure out how to that.

Comment: `v-bind="{prop1,prop2,prop3}` and in the component `props: ['prop']` see [doc](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-the-Properties-of-an-Object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the install phase to override the defaults like this:

```js
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent';

export default {
  install(Vue, options = {}) {
    let props = { ...MyComponent.props };
    Object.keys(options).forEach(k => {
      props[k] = { default: options[k] };
    });

    Vue.component('my-component', { ...MyComponent, props });
  },
};
```

What this script does is allow you to do...

```js
Vue.use(MyComponent, {prop1:"abc", props:"def"});
```

When you use the component somewhere in the app, the props are still interactive, and can be overriden, but you can leave as default. It does this by replacing the existing prop definitions with an object that only has `default` defined as the passed value. It's a bit of a hack, so I'm not sure how well it will hold up in some edge cases.

Comment: I want to register my props at Vue.use phase. Therefore I won't need to add my props to while using that component and I will use only v-model with my-component to have a better syntax

Comment: should be install(Vue, options ={}) for preventing type errors.